# Google Calendar Api v3 (java-client): setRecurrence: EXDATE

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, recurrence

Does anyone know how to set EXDATE for an event in Google Calendar API v3 (Java client)?

Using [setRecurrence(List recurrence)](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/calendar/v3/index.html): 
RRULE works perfectly, but [EXRULE, RDATE and EXDATE](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445) don't seem to work (same with getRecurrence(List recurrence): only RRULE is retrieved).

```
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;



Event event = new Event();

// ...

List RecurrenceList = new ArrayList<String>();
RecurrenceList.add("RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR");  //this works
RecurrenceList.add("EXDATE:20121019T100000Z");  //this doesn't work

event.setRecurrence(RecurrenceList);

// ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just hadn't used the UTC date, it's working now

Comment: can show example of date ? and why your `EXDATE` without `;VALUE=DATE:` ?

Comment: @waki `;VALUE=DATE:` is used for specifying dates. he's specifying datetimes