# can't set right recurrence in google calendar via api (Java)

Tags: java, api, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

```
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2020-12-16T09:00:00-03:00");
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(startDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Europe/Minsk");
event.setStart(start);

DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2020-12-16T17:00:00-03:00");
EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Europe/Minsk");
event.setEnd(end);
List<String> recurrences = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("RDATE;VALUE=PERIOD:19960403T020000Z/19960403T040000Z,19960404T010000Z/PT3H"));
```

Have a problem with setting recurrence. After executing this code duration in following events is setting like in main event and rule in string is ignoring. Can anybody help me solve that?

Comment: Can you express your desired RRULE in words? (E.g the event shall take place every Monday until October 2021)?

Comment: Better to use RDATE in my case. In my idea it will be a list of RDATE, because in future i need to change some events as a independent. I mean case if i have events on mondays and at once i need change and duration. And maybe one event once change time to tuesday with different duration.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5)
specifies:

> If the "RDATE" property is specified as a PERIOD value the duration of the recurrence instance will be the one specified by the "RDATE" property, and not the duration of the recurrence instance defined by the "DTSTART" property.

The Calendar API [Events resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#recurrence) specifies:

> List of RRULE, EXRULE, RDATE and EXDATE lines for a recurring event, as specified in RFC5545. Note that DTSTART and DTEND lines are not allowed in this field; event start and end times are specified in the start and end fields. This field is omitted for single events or instances of recurring events.

In other words, `VALUE=PERIOD` does not seem to be compatible with the Google Calendar API, because it overwrites `DTSTART`.

I recommend you to have a look at the [Calendar API documentation for recurring events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#recurring_events) to adjust your recurrent rule accordingly.

For Java, please also keep in mind that it is important to use the UTC date correctly, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867730/google-calendar-api-v3-java-client-setrecurrence-exdate).

Comment: So if i understand correctly if i want different recurrence events i need to edit it like instances? anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: I belive that if you use [RDATE;VALUE=DATE](https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/date.html) instead of [RDATE;VALUE=PERIOD](https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/period.html) - this should work.

Comment: yes, "RDATE;VALUE=DATE"  works. In my case it not a good solution , but if it the only way i should use it